# How do I retrieve XML child nodes?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file with the following contents:

```
<incometax>
  <slab>
    <lowerlimit>0</lowerlimit>
    <upperlimit>200000</upperlimit>
    <percentage>0</percentage>
  </slab>
  <slab>
    <lowerlimit>200000</lowerlimit>
    <upperlimit>500000</upperlimit>
    <percentage>10</percentage>
  </slab>
  <slab>
    <lowerlimit>500000</lowerlimit>
    <upperlimit>1000000</upperlimit>
    <percentage>20</percentage>
  </slab>
  <slab>
    <lowerlimit>1000000</lowerlimit>
    <upperlimit></upperlimit>
    <percentage>30</percentage>
  </slab>
</incometax>
```

The user has to enter a salary:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter salary:");
int salary = int.Parse(Console.Readline());
```

Depending on the salary, we have to calculate tax.

I wrote some code like this..

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("filepath");
XmlNodeList slabs = xml.SelectNodes("//slab");
```

I am getting all nodes into slabs. How to get individual child node's value?

Comment: What part of the problem are you having trouble with? Reading a file? Parsing an XML structure? Using a comparison operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop each of your `slabs` and then further query for the child elements. Then you can get the value of each element and do whatever you want with them.

Something like this:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("filepath");
XmlNodeList slabs = xml.SelectNodes("//slab");

foreach(var slab in slabs)
{
    var nodeLowerLimit = slab.SelectSingleNode("lowerLimit");
    var nodeUpperLimit = slab.SelectSingleNode("upperLimit");
    var nodePercentageLimit = slab.SelectSingleNode("percentage");

    string lowerLimit = nodeLowerLimit.Value;
    string upperLimit = nodeUpperLimit.Value;
    string percentage= nodePercentageLimit.Value;

    //do something with these values
}
```

---

If you want to match up a percentage based on input salary then you could make the following adjustments (of course @Killo has suggested an alternative that may work better - I have not used that before though so cannot confirm):

```
string percentageValue = "0";//just a default
foreach(var slab in slabs)
{
    var nodeLowerLimit = slab.SelectSingleNode("lowerLimit");
    var nodeUpperLimit = slab.SelectSingleNode("upperLimit");
    var nodePercentageLimit = slab.SelectSingleNode("percentage");

    string lowerLimit = nodeLowerLimit.Value;
    string upperLimit = nodeUpperLimit.Value;
    string percentage= nodePercentageLimit.Value;

    //check for empty strings as meaning "no limit", and check sal is within range
    if((string.IsNullOrEmpty(lowerLimit) || int.Parse(lowerLimit) <= sal) &&
       (string.IsNullOrEmpty(upperLimit) || int.Parse(upperLimit) >= sal))
    {
        percentageValue = percentage;
    }
}
//here you can convert the percentageValue to an int if you need to
```

NOTE: The above code does not check if the values are valid `int`s before parsing. If you are certain of your XML structure then you wont find a problem. However, I would recommend developing the code a bit further and using [int.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) for validation. But I will let you have a play with that ;-)

Comment: thats nice. i will try it now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
XmlNodeList slabs = xml.SelectNodes("//slab[lowerlimit > 1000 and upperlimit > 1000]");
```

Comment: can i write like this?     XmlNodeList slabs = xml.SelectNodes("//slab[lowerlimit > sal and upperlimit <= sal]");

Comment: XmlNodeList slabs = xml.SelectNodes(string.Format(@"//slab[lowerlimit > {0} and upperlimit >= {0}]", sal));

Comment: it means, the "node" which satisfies this equation is loaded into "slabs"  ??

Comment: Absolutly you are right

Comment: the beginning of the xpath string ("//") means that it will check all slab elements among all nodes